# FileUpload: Get the full path of the CSV file

Tags: sql, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, managed-bean

I'm working on a project or I want to upload an Excel CSV file that contains data from a table that I have in the database using the query `LOAD DATA LOCAL`, I test the query using the full path of the file with its path (example `C: //../file.csv`) directly in the query it works without problem, I wanted to work with the library `primefaces p: fileUpload` and when I choose a file CSV from my desktop or from another directory on my pc, it only returns the name of the file I selected and not the full path of the hit I have an error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
java.io.FileNotFoundException: extraction1.csv (The specified file can not be found)
```

Forced because there is not the full path of the file with the name of the folder, what I want is to return the name of the file with its root files from where I have selected so that my request can to execute correctly, as to show on the code below I wish that the path where the file is located when I select also be returned with the name of the file in question, and thanks.

```
prelevServ.importToDB("C:\\Users\\helyoubi\\Desktop\\Japon 2\\"+fichierUpload.getFileName());
```

My JSF form:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

    <p:fileUpload label="Choisir" value="#{importFichier.fichierUpload}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"/>

    <p:separator/>

    <p:commandButton value="Envoyer" ajax="false" action="#importFichier.importation}" />

</h:form>
```

My managedBean formula:

```
    @ManagedBean
public class ImportFichier implements Serializable{
     
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
    private UploadedFile fichierUpload;
     
    private PrelevementServices prelevServ = new PrelevementServicesImpl();
     
 
     
    public UploadedFile getFichierUpload() {
        return fichierUpload;
    }
 
 
 
 
    public void setFichierUpload(UploadedFile fichierUpload) {
        this.fichierUpload = fichierUpload;
    }
 
 
 
 
    public void importation() {
 
        if(fichierUpload.getFileName()!= null) {
         
            //prelevServ.importToDB("C:\\Users\\helyoubi\\Desktop\\Japon 2\\"+fichierUpload.getFileName());
             
            prelevServ.importToDB(fichierUpload.getFileName());
             
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", fichierUpload.getFileName()+ " is uploaded.");
             
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
             
        }else {
             
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Le chemin du fichier : "+fichierUpload.getFileName()+" est introuvable");
             
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
             
        }
         
     
        System.out.println("CSV added to your the DB Table");
         
    }
     
     
 
}
```

My request :

```
@Override
    public void importToDB(String cheminFichier) {
         
        session.beginTransaction();
         
        session.createSQLQuery("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE :filename INTO TABLE Prelevement_saisons FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'(espece,saison,departement,commune,code,attributions,realisations)").setString("filename", cheminFichier).executeUpdate();
         
        session.getTransaction().commit();
         
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just stored in a temporary location (at least with regards to larger files) so basically in your fileUploadEvent method, you'll need to write the file input stream out to a specific folder (that already exists!) on the server and then you'll know the path it can be loaded from in the database import.  If you dont have an example of how to handle the event and save the file I could probably dig up some old code for you

Comment: Yes sure if you have the script of the file input stream it will help me thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try sending .getPath():

```
prelevServ.importToDB(fichierUpload.getPath());
```